integration test gets crashed when println! is used inside function with #[ctor] attribute
Integration test is getting terminated abruptly inside function with #[ctor] attribute. Command used to run the integration test is cargo test
src/lib.rs
pub fn add(left: usize, right: usize) -> usize {
    left + right
}

tests/int_test.rs
use ctor::{ctor, dtor};

#[test]
fn it_works() {
    let result = int_test_demo::add(2, 2);
    assert_eq!(result, 4);
}

#[ctor]
fn init() {
    println!("init");
}

#[dtor]
fn term() {
    println!("term");
}

Cargo.toml
[package]
name = "int_test_demo"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
ctor = "0.2.8"

Error
running 0 tests

test result: ok. 0 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out; finished in 0.00s

     Running tests\int_test.rs (target\debug\deps\int_test-c8b50d02b8e62b99.exe)
init
fatal runtime error: thread::set_current should only be called once per thread
error: test failed, to rerun pass `--test int_test`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `C:\Users\HARSHA\Desktop\int_test_demo\target\debug\deps\int_test-c8b50d02b8e62b99.exe` (exit code: 0xc0000409, STATUS_STACK_BUFFER_OVERRUN)
note: test exited abnormally; to see the full output pass --nocapture to the harness.


A ctor runs before the Rust runtime is properly setup, you cannot print[ln]! from it. Not sure why their docs don't call that out but other, similar crates explicitly tell you so.

@cafce25 But I can do many other stuff inside #[ctor]. For eg. create a file etc. no idea what's wrong with println!

Yes, many things do not depend on the runtime being set up. But print does depend on stdout being setup. Technically it's UB to do anything in Rust before lang_start was called so it's not really documented what parts do and don't depend on it being run.

@cafce25 can you recommend a better crate than ctor which has got similar kind of functionalities?

This is fundamentally UB until Rust itself adds support for it. You could use a LazyLock for lazy initialization instead.

As a work around I found I can use libc_print crate for stdout related operations instead of rust stdout

If you want you could put our comments together in an answer, if you don't find the time I'll probably do it later.
